# Accessing a class from MainPage.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml

Forgive me, I am still new to C#. I have done some searching but cannot find anything about **.xaml.cs** and this particular issue that I am having.

I have a project in which I need to access some variables from my **MeasureLengthDevice** class from my **MainPage.xaml.cs**.

Here is some of my code in my **MeasureLengthDevice.cs** class in which I am currently trying to access **(the unitsToUse variable)**:

```
private string unitsToUse;

public MeasureLengthDevice()
{
    unitsToUse = CboMeasure.ToString();
}
```

And here is what I have in my **MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public MeasureLengthDevice()
{
    MeasureLengthDevice myMLDInstance = new MeasureLengthDevice();
    mld = myMLDInstance.MeasureLengthDevice();
}

private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     currentMeasurement.Text = unitsToUse;
}
```

My issue is, when the application runs and I click the "*startButton*", I want the *currentMeasurement* textbox to display what the *unitsToUse* variable holds. However, I cannot get access to my variable from my **MeasureLengthDevice.cs** from my **MainPage.xaml.cs**.

If I have not provided any information needed for assistance please let me know!

**UPDATED CODE**
I have changed my **MainPage.xaml.cs** to:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    MeasureLengthDevice myMLDInstance;
    public MainPage()
    {
        myMLDInstance = new MeasureLengthDevice();
        myMLDInstance.SetMeasureLengthDevice();
    }

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            currentMeasurement.Text = myMLDInstance.unitsToUse;
    }
```

And have changed **MeasureLengthDevice.cs** to:

```
public class MeasureLengthDevice : Device, IMeasuringDevice
{
    private string unitsToUse { get; set; }

    public void SetMeasureLengthDevice()
    {
        unitsToUse = CboMeasure.ToString();
    }
```

I have updated my initial post to show the changes made. The only issue I am having now is the protection level for unitsToUse, I need to keep the string private in the MeasureLengthDevice class though. If I switch it to public it does work but I need it to stay private.

Comment: try out code , and please go through concept of variable scoping ..that will help you in future ..and dont forget to upvot/accept answer ....

Answer (score 1):

you are new to c# but variable scoping is not new to programming language, here you are declaring variable in one method and try to acess it in antoher method but variable you declared is in scope of first method only so you cannot access it in other method of your class.

so its better to increase scrop of variable to both the method by putting variable in larger scope i.e at class leavel so both method can access variable

following is you code

```
MeasureLengthDevice myMLDInstance;
public MeasureLengthDevice()
{ 
  myMLDInstance = new MeasureLengthDevice();
    mld = myMLDInstance.MeasureLengthDevice();
}

private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(myMLDInstance!=null)
     currentMeasurement.Text = myMLDInstance.unitsToUse;
}
```

---

**MeasureLengthDevice.cs**

```
public class MeasureLengthDeviceInfo 
{
 public string unitsToUse {get; set;}

  public void SetMeasureLengthDevice()
  {
    unitsToUse = CboMeasure.ToString();        
  }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
public class MainPage
{
 MeasureLengthDeviceInfo myMLDInstance;
 public MainPage()
 {
    myMLDInstance = new MeasureLengthDeviceInfo();
    myMLDInstance.SetMeasureLengthDevice();
 }

 private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     currentMeasurement.Text = myMLDInstance.unitsToUse;
 }
}
```

Comment: @BuckyBuckwild - change this line private string unitsToUse; to public string unitsToUse;

Comment: @BuckyBuckwild - and MeasureLengthDevice change this class name to to MeasureLengthDeviceInfo ...as you have both the class with same name you are getting error of it

Comment: @BuckyBuckwild - check code updated by me ...you have to write code something like that...i suggest please go through basic of C# you will understand things

Comment: @BuckyBuckwild Create a property with backing field and maybe read some books about object oriented programming

Comment: @BuckyBuckwild - if you dont create property as public how can you acess it ...other way to provide access i to create method in you class and expose it